# White-spaces appearing around text even though not entered

Tags: html, css

The text I entered has no white space, but the content output use `white-space:pre` with a lot of white spaces.

```
.pre { white-space:pre; }
```

[image]

Comment: May be that white spaces coming from browser default styles. Use normalizer and try again.

Comment: @Juan I am sure white-space is not the root of your problem, it is best if you can show some code

Comment: Thank you. I have no problem writing td for HTML on one line